# What are the minimum requirements to pass the FAA medical exam?

Tags: medical, faa-approval

What are the requirements like height, weight, sight to pass the medical exam for getting a pilot's license ?

Are there any medical conditions that would make someone to fail it?
I know daltonism would be one of those.

Comment: [Related](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/13593/what-mental-health-standards-must-a-candidate-meet-in-order-to-qualify-for-a-pil)

Comment: Many medical conditions make you fail the FAA medical exam. If there weren't such conditions, they wouldn't *have* the medical exam,

Comment: In the US there are three classes of medical, each with more stringent requirements so you need to specify what kind of flying you intend to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no height or weight requirements as far as I know and you dont need perfect vision. I wear glasses and have a "corrective lens" note on my medical. I think that at minimum your vision needs to be correctable to 20/20. See [this link](https://www.faa.gov/pilots/become/medical/) for some information as well as the [information for doctors here](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/avs/offices/aam/ame/guide/standards/). You can also get special dispensation for certain medical conditions.

On a small side note, if you are asking this in relation to a Private Pilot License, they may be doing away with the current third class medical regulations which will ease the regulations greatly.

Answer (score 2):

All specific requirements to obtain a U.S. FAA Medical Certificate are listed in [Part §67](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/retrieveECFR?gp=&SID=55798c27635651597638585dc8d4100d&mc=true&n=pt14.2.67&r=PART&ty=HTML) of Title 14 of the Federal Aviation Regulations (FARs).

> [§67.1](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/retrieveECFR?gp=&SID=55798c27635651597638585dc8d4100d&mc=true&n=pt14.2.67&r=PART&ty=HTML) Applicability:
>
> This part prescribes the medical standards and certification
>   procedures for issuing medical certificates for airmen and for
>   remaining eligible for a medical certificate.

It lists all specifications that have to do with the *eye, ear, nose, throat, and equilibrium, mental, neurologic, cardiovascular, general medical condition and also any discretionary issuance*.

To answer your specific question, you **don't have to have a minimum/maximum height-weight to obtain a medical certificate**. The operation you conduct and the company you conduct it with **may** have certain height-weight requirements.